# How do I count how many items is in an array and output a different response depending on the number using Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

In this case, I am preparing a Handlebars template which is flexible depending on how many items are in a given list. The general idea is that each item will run down the list as follows:

`List Item One`
`List Item Two`
`List Item Three`
`List Item Four`
`List Item Five`

But as soon as there are more than 5 items, they should be split across two columns as follows:

`List Item One   | List Item Two`
`List Item Three | List Item Four`
`List Item Five  | List Item Six`

I have tried making use of the `@index` variable (as stated in the [documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index)), however, this only gives the index of the current iteration, not the total number of items in the array. For example, this code snippet:

```html
{{#each items}}
    {{#gt @index 4}}
        <div class="col-sm-6 list-view-item">
            <a href="{{FileRef.textValue}}">{{Title.textValue}}</a>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="col-sm-12 list-view-item">
            <a href="{{FileRef.textValue}}">{{Title.textValue}}</a>
        </div>
    {{/gt}}
{{/each}}
```

This will return the following:

`List Item One   | List Item Two`
`List Item Three | List Item Four`
`List Item Five`
`List Item Six`
`List Item Seven`

I have tried using `{{#gt items.length 4}}` but this doesn't work as expected and will always return as false. It would be preferable not to create a custom helper unless it is necessary.

Is there a way to count how many items are in an array and run a 'greater than' `{{#gt}}` conditional against that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem with using `{{#gt items.length 4}}` is that it is getting the length of each item in the array, rather than the length of the entire array.

In order to get the desired effect, it is required to reference the *parent* array by using:

`{{#gt ../items.length 4}}`

With that being the case, the following code snippet provides the correct result:

```html
{{#each items}}
    {{#gt ../items.length 4}}
        <div class="col-sm-6 list-view-item">
            <a href="{{FileRef.textValue}}">{{Title.textValue}}</a>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="col-sm-12 list-view-item">
            <a href="{{FileRef.textValue}}">{{Title.textValue}}</a>
        </div>
    {{/gt}}
{{/each}}
```